# PHP: Smallest multiple of 225 that is all 1's and 0's

Tags: php

```
echo "The smallest multiple of 225 that is only 1's and 0's is: ";

$multiple = (integer) 225;
$factor = (integer) 1;

while (!isDecimalBinary($multiple))
{
   $multiple += 225;
   $factor += 1;
}  

 echo $multiple.':'.$factor;


function isDecimalBinary($number)
    {
       $stringNumber = (string) $number;
       $arrayNumber = str_split($stringNumber); 
       foreach ($arrayNumber as $item)
       {
          if ($item != '0' || $item != '1')
          {
             return FALSE;
          }
       }
       return TRUE;
    }
```

I'm tired. It's late. I can't figure where the mistake is here.
Also, I'd thrilled to find a less time consuming method if there's any math tricks to find if a decimal number is all binary digits.

Comment: $arrayNumber = explode($stringNumber); on which basis you are exploding?

Comment: You know it can't be 255, 765, etc. So start at 510 and increment 510 at a time.

Comment: http://ideone.com/21baui

Comment: Is it given that there is actually a multiple of 225 that only comprises zeroes and ones? Did you mean 255?

Comment: Yes, there is. 11111111100.

Comment: You're right. It takes 49382716 multiplications :) my machine took a while to calculate it. The problem is likely because you need 64bit integers.

Comment: 123, would you please clarify whether multiple is intended to be 255 or 225? I've answered the question based on 255, and your comment on winterblood's answer implies that 255 was the number you intended, but your question and code both indicate 225 is correct.

Comment: This "question" has garnered a lot of attention for not being an actual question. You've presented us with nothing but some code and we're to infer the question from it. Sorry, but I'm flagging this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the specific problem with your code:

explode() doesn't do what you think it does. explode() requires a delimeter parameter, and splits the string out into arrays using that parameter as a separator. If you replace explode() in your code with str_split(), which simply converts the string into an array of characters, the function works correctly.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

---

Now, this doesn't actually solve your problem, because you're going to wait a really long time for PHP to chug through and brute-force the correct answer like this. You know how to run a debugger in PHP, right? Debug through your loop and see how obviously inefficient it is. For example, when you hit 2250, you can know without any calculation that the answer cannot possibly be less than 10,000, but you keep checking all the intervening values that cannot possibly start with a 1.

It becomes clear pretty quickly that this is not the correct approach. What if you look at the problem the other way around, and check numbers consisting only of 1's and 0's to see if they're multiples of 255?

Updated solution (http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dmw-zif)

```
$i = 1;
$val = $i;
while ($val % 255)
{
  $bin = decbin($i++);
  $val = (integer) $bin;
}  

echo "The smallest multiple of 255 that is only 1's and 0's is: $val, which is equal to 255 *".($val/255);
```

Comment: This gives me a white page.

Comment: 1000110 (binary) = 70 (decimal), not 71. Furthermore, neither decimal number is a multiple of 255, nor do they consist of only ones and zeros.

Comment: I don't know why you'd get an error from the code, it runs in my local system and on phpfiddle fine. I've linked a phpfiddle with the updated version of my solution in the answer.

Comment: @Herbert You've misunderstood the output of the function. 1000110 is not a binary number in the output, it's a decimal number that is the smallest multiple of 255 to contain only 1's and 0's. The 71 was an off-by-one error that I've fixed in the updated version, and I updated the output to make its meaning clearer: hope that helps.

Comment: @Herbert The 70 was also incorrect - It was supposed to be the multiple of 255 that contained only 1s and 0s, but I output the number of iterations my loop required, instead. I've fixed the error.

Comment: My apologies. I saw that you had used $bin in the result and took it to be binary. I like your approach to the problem so I upvoted your answer. Nevertheless, it fails for me in PHP for 225 because it exceeds the maximum execution time. :(

Comment: @Herbert, No worries. I'm not sure why you'd be having a runtime problem for 225, though. It takes 2045 iterations to find the answer for 225, which takes less than a second on phpfiddle.

Comment: Running Wampserver in 64-bit Win 7 on a 2.8 GHz processor and it's timing out after 30 seconds with no result. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 225 instead of 255 in your code.

Also you may want to use `str_split($stringNumber, 1)` instead of `explode($stringNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

You forget here explode parameter

```
$arrayNumber = explode($explode_parameter,$stringNumber);
```

Comment: In this case, the `$explode_parameter` should be the empty string, but that doesn't work in PHP :)

Comment: Good observation but I really needed a str_split()

Comment: @123 You don't even need `str_split()` or a loop in fact; see also my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not calling `explode()` properly, you can't call it without a delimiter. You could use `str_split()` instead, but it can be even simpler:

```
function isDecimalBinary($number)
{
        return strspn($number, '01') == strlen($number);
}
```

Btw, this code requires 64bit integers, otherwise they're turned into doubles and lose precision.

Alternatively, you could use `gmp`.

```
$multiple = gmp_init(225);
$factor = 1;

$result = $multiple;

while (!isDecimalBinary(gmp_strval($result))) {
    ++$factor;
    $result = gmp_add($result, $multiple);
}

echo gmp_strval($result).':'.$factor;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isDecimalBinary($number)
{
    return $number == base_convert(base_convert($number,2,10),10,2);
}
```

Convert it to base 10 (with precision loss if not base 2) then back to 2. If they're different, it's not all 1s and 0s.